# How to declare a private setter for a property using F#

Tags: f#

In C#, we can declare a private setter for a property.
How can this be done using F#?

Specifically, how can I ensure that the state of a property can only be changed from within the class only?

For example, how do we declare the FirstName setter property as private, as in C#?

```cs
public string FirstName { get; private set; }
```

```ml
type SomeViewModel() =
    inherit ViewModel()
    let mutable firstName = ""
    let mutable lastName = ""

    member this.FirstName
        with get() = firstName 
        and set(value) =
            firstName <- value
            base.notifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.FirstName @>)

    member this.LastName
        with get() = lastName 
        and set(value) =
            lastName <- value
            base.notifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.LastName @>)

    member this.GetFullName() = 
        sprintf "%s %s" (this.FirstName) (this.LastName)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
member this.FirstName
    with get() = firstName 
    and private set(value) =
        firstName <- value
        base.notifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.FirstName @>)
```

This is shown directly in the [MSDN F# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the UserVoice suggestion for it.

Apparently it was considered for F# 3.0, and then cut.
It is still "approved-in-principle."

https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/7640829-allow-access-modifies-to-auto-properties-getters-a